# Python pattern matching regex

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

```
value=['0.203973Noerror(0)', '0.237207Noerror(0)','-1Timedout(-2)']

pattern=re.compile("\D\\(\d|[-]\d\\)")

temp=[]

for i in range(0,len(value)):
    err=pattern.match(value[i])
    if err:
        temp=value[i]
print(temp)
```

I want parsing the value:

```
[Noerror(0),Noerror(0),Timedout(-2)]
```

But when I'm processing code, the result is:

```
[0.203973Noerror(0),0.237207Noerror(0)',-1Timedout(-2)]
```

I don't know why this result comes out... please advice to me.

Comment: Change `match` to `search`, as `match` always starts matching from the beginning of the string.

Comment: You may use `re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+\(-?[0-9]+\)$', value[i]).group()`

Comment: The following regular expression should work, too: `re.search(r'[^(0-9]+\([^)]+?\)',value[i]).group()`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz) answer:

```
import re


results = []
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-z]+\([0-9-]+\))', flags=re.I)
value = ['0.203973Noerror(0)', '0.237207Noerror(0)','-1Timedout(-2)']

for v in value:
    match = pattern.search(v)
    if match:
        results.append(match.group(1))

print results
```

Answer (score 0):

For bonus points, you can split the numbers from the errors into tuples:

```
import re

value=['0.203973Noerror(0)', '0.237207Noerror(0)','-1Timedout(-2)']
temp=[]

for val in value:
    err = re.match(r'^([0-9.-]+)(.+)$', val)
    if err:
        temp.append(err.groups())

print temp
```

Gives the following:

```
[('0.203973', 'Noerror(0)'), ('0.237207', 'Noerror(0)'), ('-1', 'Timedout(-2)')]
```

If you just want the errors, then:

```
temp2 = [ t[1] for t in temp ]
print temp2
```

Gives:

```
['Noerror(0)', 'Noerror(0)', 'Timedout(-2)']
```

Comment: I have one more question, if the value is as below:
value=['0.203973 No error (0)', '0.237207 No error (0)','-1 Timed out (-2)']
Can I apply to same regex rule on the code?

Comment: Slight amendment - add `\s*` between the groups:  `re.match(r'^([0-9.-]+)\s*(.+)$', val)`  gives:  `[('0.203973', 'Noerror (0)'), ('0.237207', 'Noerror (0)'), ('-1', 'Timedout (-2)')]`